# What does 'imperative thinking' mean?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have seen this a lot that someone is criticized for thinking imperatively regarding their algorithm/solution, even though they seem to be experienced with functional programming.

So I want to know what 'imperative thinking' means, and how one can avoid thinking imperatively?

Comment: An imperative program is (basically) one which has an intrinsic notion of global state. To avoid imperative thinking is simply to avoid designing algorithms which make use of some sort of global state. Haskell has no notion of global state (outside of `IO` at least) so it makes sense to avoid relying on something which your language doesn't provide. Although, even in imperative languages, it is much easier to reason about programs which don't use any global state. Similar things can be said about 'mutability'.

Comment: I would say that "imperative thinking" is to think of everything as a sequence of steps or statements that would be evaluated in order. So instead of "compute a from b from c" one would say "compute c *then* compute b from that *then* compute a from that". Which is just unnecessary.

Comment: “With enough effort, it is possible to write Fortran code in any language.”